# converting a jade if statement to handlebars (hbs)

Tags: node.js, twitter, express, pug, handlebars.js

I've been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXEIIF_5728) tutorial and I've been able to convert each jade line to hbs apart from this one;

`- if (user_open.id != user.id)`

I tried this;

`{{#if "user_open.id != user.id" }}`

but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlebars is logicless so you can't use the `!=` operator directly. You'll need to pre-compute in javascript a boolean value you can pass to the template when you render such as `isOther` so you can do `{{#if isOther}}` in your template or create a block helper function so you can do `{{#isOther user user_open}}`